# tornado requesthandler overwrite head method

Tags: python, http, tornado, requesthandler, http-head

I'm using tornado framework of python to build up my site, and I encountered a problem. Now there is a requirement my site should response to head method, but in tornado, it would only return a 405 response, while I need to return the header of the request, so how to implement the head method of tornado's requesthandler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do this recently to keep Mandril happy.

It turns out to be simple - create a head(self) function in your Handler:

```
class InboundEmailHandler(base.BaseHandler):

    def head(self):
        """ Satisfy Mandril that this url exists"""
        self.finish()
```